# Multiple gitolite "hosting user" accounts

Tags: git, gitolite

From http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#hu

"When you install gitolite in ssh mode, you pick one specific user on the Unix system to be the "hosting user". This is the user whose name goes into the repo URLs your users will be cloning, for example ssh://git@server/repo, or the simpler form git@server:repo."

It quite clearly states *one specific user*, but can we also have *multiple* hosting users, e.g. `git.1`, `git.2`, each with their own repositories, and which we could access separately using e.g. `git.1@server:repo`, `git.2@server:anotherrepo`, etc?

Comment: Sure, that should work. It seems really easy to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can work if you install gitolite using those accounts, in their respective home directory.

```
su - git.1
mkdir -p ~/bin

git clone git://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite
gitolite/install -ln ~/bin          # please use absolute path here
gitolite setup -pk yourname.pub
```

(repeat for `git.2` and so on)

But don't mix access and hosting: `git.1`, `git.2` and other accounts could be simply declared in a `gitolite.config`, accessing their own repo, while using the unique git account as the hosting service user account.

Answer (score 0):

That same section says, in the last line:

```
Of course you can have any number of "hosting users", but that's rare.
```

Is that what you meant?